# Cannot Locate .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, centos

Good morning team,

I need help, I'm in charge of a Web server CENTOS handling the web of my work is a little disorganized and access to the site is restricted by http, I need to add users so that they can authenticate to the site but I can not find the .htaccess file, I've tried everything [locate, find, updatedb, ls -a, etc ...] I need your help please.

Capture of the root folder of the portal:

[root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJEv4.jpg)

Here a capture of the passwd file:
[passwd file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVXK3.jpg)

Comment: What's the question again?

Comment: I need to find the .htaccess or a way to add users

Comment: Why don't you just take the top level server configuration?

Comment: What do you mean with Top Level Server Configuration? sorry, i don't have much experience administering servers

Comment: i was reading my httpd configuration file and i read the configuration needed to use auth basic, let me add a user with htpasswd and i will tell you the result.

Comment: Thanks my friend, now i got it and i did it, simple adding a user trough the command htpasswd /var/www/passwd/passwords yguzman, so thanks :)

Comment: Well done. That's how you really learn something :)